# working with copies of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

When do variables made from arrays act as pointers to the array and when do they act as copies of the array?

For instance if I have an array named `Array1`

```
a1=Array1;
```

is `a1` a copy or a pointer to the array.

If I modify `a1` will it also modify `Array1`. By modify I mean change a value, push something into the array, sort, or any other way you could modify an array.

thanks,

Comment: `x = [1,2,3]; y = x; y[0] = 7; console.log(x)` will output `7,2,3`. arrays in JS are objects, and when you copy an object via `newobj = origobj`, you're just creating a reference. you need to CLONE the array object to create a truly independent copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable assignment in JavaScript **never** makes copies for [non-primitives](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2) (everything that isn't a [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Values)).

[Assignment for all non-values copies *references*.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)

Answer (score 1):

A variable in javascript holds a reference to the array.

If you copy the variable value with `arr2 = arr1`, you copy the reference to the same array. So any change to `arr2` is a change to `arr1`.

If you want another variable to hold a reference to a copy, so that you may change the second array without changing the first one, use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) :

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice();
```

Comment: I don't remember why exactly, but I think you want that to be `arr1.slice(0)`

Comment: You may also want to note that `.slice()` only creates a *shallow* copy of the array.